# Расшифровка коротких ссылок

Tags: php

заинтересовал скрипт по расшифровке коротких ссылок
Есть ссылка, например: http://langamepp.com/chtst/DAFB5E48618B4D60DB8B69822BB7DB74EBC36A7F50BD3141E9A3B93CFB0B0AF50A41771313FE250CA8D6
И она отсылается на http://live-gtrkomsk.cdnvideo.ru/gtrkomsk/gtrkomsk.sdp/playlist.m3u8
Интересует как получить ссылку на которую она ссылается.
Нашел онлайн сервис http://backlinks-checker.dimax.biz/tools/rasshifrovka-korotkih-ssilok.php
Интересует как работает скрипт?
Зарание спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как это работает в браузере (к чему вы привыкли):

- браузер переходит по ссылке, а веб-сервер ему указывает на новую ссылку (редирект)
- браузер переходит по новой ссылке
- и так далее, пока не получит окончательный вариант (или будет исчерпан лимит редиректов в браузере, он нужен против бесконечных переходов)

Редирект осуществляется через `3xx` [коды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#3xx)

Поэтому нам нужна сетевая утилита, которая будет переходить последовательно по адресам до тех пор, пока не получит окончательную страницу.

Можно сделать через `curl`:

```
curl -sL --head http://langamepp.com/chtst/DAFB5E48618B4D60DB8B69822BB7DB74EBC36A7F50BD3141E9A3B93CFB0B0AF50A41771313FE250CA8D6 | grep Location
```

Получим

```
Location: http://langamepp.com/mnogoust.mp4
```

Немного про использованные опции:

- `-s` подавляет вывод прогресс-бара
- `-L` следовать редиректам
- `-head` - запрашиваем только заголовки

`grep Location` - фильтрация по слову `Location` - это именно то, куда при `3xx` коде идет переход.

Можно сделать и чисто средствами PHP, суть та же, курл там есть. Мне нравится более короткий вариант, который вызывает оболочку:

```
$uri = 'http://langamepp.com/chtst/DAFB5E48618B4D60DB8B69822BB7DB74EBC36A7F50BD3141E9A3B93CFB0B0AF50A41771313FE250CA8D6';
$cmd = sprintf('curl -sL --head %s | grep Location', escapeshellarg($uri));
$data = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $data;
```

Также есть ответ на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288130/php-curl-following-redirects#10288230), там есть обработка варианта перехода через JavaScript